# Sum array within array and return a new array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
$r1[$db_rate_type] = Array($db_rate_in, $db_rate_out, $db_rate_desc);
$r2[$db_rate_type] = Array($db_rate_in, $db_rate_out, $db_rate_desc);
```

Lets say the value of each array looks like this:

```
Array 1:
[1] = [1400] [20] ["Standard timelønn"]
[2] = [NULL] [20] ["Kveldstillegg"]

Array 2:
[1] = [NULL] [20] ["Standard timelønn"]
[2] = [1500] [20] ["Kveldstillegg"]
```

How can I sum the value of the array, but keep the counting IDs at the beginning?

I have tried the following code:

```
$c = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $a, $b);
```

But it counts only for one array added to another array, and not arrays WITHIN arrays. What I prefer to have returned is the following:

```
Array returned:
[1] = [1400] [40] ["Standard timelønn"]
[2] = [1500] [40] ["Kveldstillegg"]
```

So how can I do this, but have it as effective as possible?

Full code of the database fetch etc. can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/4PHyhDHJ)

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? Depending on it there could be different solutions.

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. It is not fair on the users spent time writing the answers you invalidated. Next time, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with 5.6 (argument unpacking is needed)

```
<?php

$r1 = [
    1 => [1, 2, "one"],
    2 => [5, 5, "two"],
];
$r2 = [
    1 => [null, 20, "one"],
    2 => [1, 0, "two"],
];

$sum = function (array $a1, array $a2) {
    return array_map(
        function($e1) {
            return (is_int($e1) || is_null($e1)) ? array_sum(func_get_args()) : $e1;
        },
        $a1,
        $a2
    );
};


$res = [];
foreach ($r1 as $k => $a) {
    $res[$k] = $sum($r1[$k], $r2[$k]);
}

var_dump($res);

// Output:
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(22)
    [2] =>
    string(3) "one"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(6)
    [1] =>
    int(5)
    [2] =>
    string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/i10rJ

Comment: Se updated question, also, I want the array key to be the same, to start with 1 then go on to 2 etc.

Comment: And again: what's your PHP version?

Comment: Running version 5.3 Error is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/conn/subdomener/projects/functions.php on line 1067`

Comment: 5.3 is a very old version, please update. Otherwise you should change all the `[*]` to `array(*)`.

Comment: Returned `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to {closure}() must be an array, null given, called in /home/connecti/subdomener/projects/functions.php on line 1071 and defined in /home/connecti/subdomener/projects/functions.php on line 1058`

Comment: added my entire fetch code... It's important that the result is returned exactly the same way as `$r1`
 is being fetched, only difference is that I need to add `$r2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106007/discussion-between-ksimka-and-gjert-ingar-gjersund).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
<?php
//your needs
/* 
$d = array(
    0 => array(1400, 40, 1500, 30),
    1 => array(1500, 40, null, 30)
);
*/

//a
$a = array(
    0 => array(1400,20,null,15),
    1 => array(null, 20, null, 15)
);

//b
$b = array(
    0 => array(null,20,1500,15),
    1 => array(1500, 20, null, 15)
);

//c
$c = array_map(function () {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sumArray = array();
    foreach ($args as $k=>$subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
            @$sumArray[$id]+=$value;
        }
    }
    return $sumArray;
}, $a, $b);

//result
print_r($c);
?>
```

[Result](https://eval.in/534594)